# ZingCharts horizontal stacked bar chart X-Axis labels being cut off

Tags: javascript, zingchart

I've created a simple horizontal bar chart. The labels on the X-Axis are being cut off as shown in the snippet below. I need to show the full label of 'X Axis Row A'. I've tried changing the width of the chart but that doesn't help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ZingChart</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartDiv"></div>
<script src='http://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js'></script>
<script>
var chartData={
    "type":"hbar",
    "stacked":true,
    "stack-type":"normal", // Also accepts "100%"
    "title":{
        "text":"X-Axis Row Label Cut Off Example"
    },
    "scale-x":{
        "values":["X Axis Row B","X Axis Row A"],
    },
    "scale-y":{
        "format":"%v%",
    },
    "series":[{
        "background-color":"rgb(248,51,45)",
        "text":"Negative",
        "values":[-11,-22]
    },{
        "background-color":"rgb(120,152,55)",
        "text":"Positive",
        "values":[35,45]
    }]
};
window.onload=function(){
    var x = zingchart.render({
        id:'chartDiv',
        height:200,
        width:600,
        data:chartData
    });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I finally figured it out. If you use the 'plotarea' key you can then specify the margins. For example:

```
"plotarea":{
    "margin":"40px 20px 50px 100px"
}
```

Updated example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ZingChart</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartDiv"></div>
<script src='http://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js'></script>
<script>
var chartData={
    "type":"hbar",
    "stacked":true,
    "stack-type":"normal", // Also accepts "100%"
    "title":{
        "text":"Add Margin Example"
    },
    "plotarea": {
        "margin":"40px 20px 50px 100px"
    },
    "scale-x":{
        "values":["X Axis Row B","X Axis Row A"],
    },
    "scale-y":{
        "format":"%v%",
    },
    "series":[{
        "background-color":"rgb(248,51,45)",
        "text":"Negative",
        "values":[-11,-22]
    },{
        "background-color":"rgb(120,152,55)",
        "text":"Positive",
        "values":[35,45]
    }]
};
window.onload=function(){
    var x = zingchart.render({
        id:'chartDiv',
        height:200,
        width:600,
        data:chartData
    });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the margins definitely works. You can also use "margin":"dynamic" in the "plotarea" object. There's a demo in the docs that shows some long labels accommodated by this attribute. http://www.zingchart.com/docs/json-attributes-syntax/graph-objects/plotarea/

I'm on the ZingChart team so feel free to reach out if you have any additional questions on this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ZingChart</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartDiv"></div>
<script src='http://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js'></script>
<script>
var chartData={
    "type":"hbar",
    "stacked":true,
    "stack-type":"normal", // Also accepts "100%"
    "title":{
        "text":"Add Margin Example",
        "adjust-layout":1
    },
    "plotarea": {
        "margin":"dynamic"
    },
    "scale-x":{
        "values":["X Axis Row B","X Axis Row A"],
    },
    "scale-y":{
        "format":"%v%",
    },
    "series":[{
        "background-color":"rgb(248,51,45)",
        "text":"Negative",
        "values":[-11,-22]
    },{
        "background-color":"rgb(120,152,55)",
        "text":"Positive",
        "values":[35,45]
    }]
};
window.onload=function(){
    var x = zingchart.render({
        id:'chartDiv',
        height:200,
        width:600,
        data:chartData
    });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks - that's useful to know :) I did find it doesn't seem to take into consideration space required by the 'title' in my example.

Comment: John in this case, you can add the adjust-layout attribute to the title object to fix that. Can't include a snippet in this comment, so I'm going to add it to my answer above.